# Design pattern to ensure on_close() is called once after all async r/w's are finished?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, design-patterns, io, boost-asio

This question is asked from the context of Boost ASIO (C++).

Say you are using a library to do some async i/o on a socket, where:

- you are always waiting to receive data
- you occasionally send some data

Since you are always waiting to receive data (e.g. you trigger another `async_read()` from your completion handler), at any given time, you will either have:

1. an async read operation in progress
2. an async read operation in progress **and** an async write operation in progress

Now say you wanted to call some other function, `on_close()`, when the connection closes. In Boost ASIO, a connection error or `cancel()` will cause any oustanding async reads/writes to give an error to your completion handler. But there is no guarantee whether you are in scenario 1. or 2., nor is there a guarantee that the write will error before the read or vice versa. So to implement this, I can only imagine adding two variables called `is_reading` and `is_writing` which are set to true by `async_read()` and `async_write()` respectively, and set to false by the completion handlers. Then, from either completion handler, when there is an error and I think the connection may be closing, I would check if there is still an async operation in the opposite direction, and call `on_close()` if not.

The code, more or less:

```cpp
atomic_bool is_writing;
atomic_bool is_reading;

...

void read_callback(error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  is_reading = false;

  if (error)
  {
    if (!is_writing) on_close();
  }
  else
  {
    process_data(bytes_transferred);
  
    async_read(BUF_SIZE);  // this will set is_reading to true
  }
}

void write_callback(error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  is_writing = false;

  if (error)
  {
    if (!is_reading) on_close();
  }
}
```

Assume that this is a single-threaded app, but the thread is handling multiple sockets so you can't just let the thread end.

Is there a better way to design this? To make sure `on_close()` is called after the last async operation finishes?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common patterns is to use `enable_shared_from_this` and binding all completion handlers ("continuations") to it.

That way if the async call chain ends (be it due to error or regular completion) the shared_ptr referee will be freed.

You can see many many examples by me using Asio/Beast [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20enable_shared_from_this%20shared_from_this)

You can put your close logic in a destructor, or if that, too, involves async calls, you can post it on the same strand/chain.

### Advanced Ideas

If your traffic is full-duplex and one side fails in a way that necessitates cancelling the other direction, you can `post` cancellation on the strand and the async call will abort (e.g. with `error_code` `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`).

Even more involved would be to create a custom IO service, where the lifetime of certain "backend" entities is governed by "handle" types. This is probably often overkill, but if you are writing a foundational framework that will be used in a larger number of places, you might consider it. I think this is a good starter: [How to design proper release of a boost::asio socket or wrapper thereof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239208/how-to-design-proper-release-of-a-boostasio-socket-or-wrapper-thereof/43239699#43239699) (be sure to follow the comment links).

Answer (score 0):

You can leave error handling logic only inside `read_callback`.